# How to protect MS Word document

Tags: microsoft-word

I am trying to protect a Word document with tools -> protect document but it does not protect anything. I would like to protect header and footer.

Answer (score 1):

This article explains with visuals how to protect a Word 2003 document: (I suppose that you are using Word 2003)

[How to Protect a Word Document](http://www.ehow.com/how_2264762_protect-word-document.html)